# Apache poi: insert text in a paragraph and view track changes in a word document

Tags: java, spring, ms-word, apache-poi

I´m using Apache poi library with java 11. I´m trying to see the track changes after adding a new text into a paragraph in a word document:

```
 private void setSectionRun(XWPFParagraph paragraph){
    // insert xml node
    paragraph.getCTP().addNewIns().setAuthor("Kane");

    XWPFRun newRun = paragraph.createRun();
    newRun.setText(". Hello world");
    paragraph.addRun(newRun);
}
```

And I get the following output in document.xml. In this case the track changes is not working:

```
<w:ins w:author="Kane"/>
<w:r>
    <w:t>. Hello world</w:t>
</w:r>
```

In any case, if I manually edit the document I can see the track changes and accept or reject the insertion with the following result:

```
<w:ins w:id="0" w:author="Kane" w:date="2022-04-20T15:33:00Z">
    <w:r w:rsidR="00B00A22">
        <w:t>. Hello world</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:ins>
```

The problem is that I can't activate the track changes when I insert a new text in a paragraph with Apache poi.

On the other hand, with `newRun.getCTR().getRPr().addNewRPrChange().setAuthor("Kane")`
the format changes of a `XWPFRun`are detected and I can see the change control correctly, but not the new text insertions at the paragraph level.

Is there a way to enable the track change on new text inserts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache POI does not support tracking changes up to now.

As you see in your XML, your code places an empty `w:ins` element above the `w:r` element. But Microsoft Word wraps the `w:r` element with the `w:ins` element. The `w:r` element is a child element of the `w:ins` element.

One possibility to code that would be having a class `XWPFInsRun` which extends `XWPFRun` and a method to create such `XWPFInsRun` in a `XWPFParagraph`. Doing this one has all options of `XWPFRun` extended by the options of  `CTRunTrackChange` - author and date for example.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class CreateWordInsRun {
    
 static XWPFInsRun createInsRun(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String author, java.util.Calendar date) {
  CTRunTrackChange trackChange = paragraph.getCTP().addNewIns();
  trackChange.setAuthor(author);
  trackChange.setDate(date);
  trackChange.addNewR();
  return new XWPFInsRun(
    trackChange,
    trackChange.getRArray(0),
    paragraph
   );
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph 1");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFInsRun insRun = createInsRun(paragraph, "Kane", new java.util.GregorianCalendar());
  insRun.setText("Paragraph 2 inserted by Kane");
  System.out.println(insRun.getAuthor());
  System.out.println(insRun.getDate());
  
  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph 3");
    
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./WordDocument.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();    
 }
 
 static class XWPFInsRun extends XWPFRun {
  private CTRunTrackChange trackChange;
  public XWPFInsRun(CTRunTrackChange trackChange, CTR run, IRunBody p) {
   super(run, p);
   this.trackChange = trackChange;
  }
  public String getAuthor() {
   return this.trackChange.getAuthor();   
  }
  public void setAuthor(String author) {
   this.trackChange.setAuthor(author);   
  }
  public java.util.Calendar getDate() {
   return this.trackChange.getDate();   
  }
  public void setDate(java.util.Calendar date) {
   this.trackChange.setDate(date);   
  }
  //... further methods
 }
}
```

Comment: I've added your code to my project and it works fine.

Comment: First of all I create a model class with `static class XWPFInsRun extends XWPFRun{}` and on the other hand I added `static XWPFInsRun createInsRun()` in a utils class and I call this method when I need it. I checked the documet.xml and the xml nodes are created correctly. As before, your code has been of great help. Thank you very much Axel