# Apache poi: insert run at specific position in paragraph

Tags: java, spring, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm working with Apache poi in java 11. I'm trying to insert a new run (with control change) at a specific position in a paragraph but currently the run is inserted at the end of the paragraph.

Here my code:

```java
private void insertCTRun(List<XWPFParagraph> paraList){
    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paraList) {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
        // Loop runs
        for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
            String text = r.getText(0);
            // Find specific text
            if (text != null && text.contains("TextToFind")) {

                XmlCursor cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
                cursor.toNextSibling();

                // Add a new track run
                XWPFTrackRun newCTRun = createInsRun(paragraph, SummaryCommonConstants.NAME_APP, new java.util.GregorianCalendar());

                newCTRun.setText("NewText");
            }
        }
    }
}

// Add track change
private static XWPFTrackRun createInsRun(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String author, java.util.Calendar date) {
    CTRunTrackChange trackChange = paragraph.getCTP().addNewIns();
    trackChange.setAuthor(author);
    trackChange.setDate(date);
    trackChange.addNewR();
    return new XWPFTrackRun(
            trackChange,
            trackChange.getRArray(0),
            paragraph
    );
}

// Model with track change properties
public class XWPFTrackRun extends XWPFRun {

    private CTRunTrackChange trackChange;

    public XWPFTrackRun(CTRunTrackChange trackChange, CTR run, IRunBody p) {
        super(run, p);
        this.trackChange = trackChange;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return this.trackChange.getAuthor();
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.trackChange.setAuthor(author);
    }
    public java.util.Calendar getDate() {
        return this.trackChange.getDate();
    }
    public void setDate(java.util.Calendar date) {
        this.trackChange.setDate(date);
    }

}
```

I would like to insert the run with a "NewText" after the text "TextToFind" but I get the following result:

```
This is an example with TextToFind working with apache poi NewText
```

Is there a way to insert the run "NewText" at that specific position?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Biggest problem is to find the position of the new run. You cannot rely on "TextToFind" be in its own text-run. It could be a part of a text run ("with TextToFind working") as well as split into multiple text-runs ("Text""To""Find"). Microsoft Word is very special in how it stores text-runs.

Comment: Also, what is `XWPFTrackRun` in your code? What you would need is a special [XWPFParagraph.insertNewRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#insertNewRun-int-) for your `XWPFTrackRun`. See [XWPFParagraph.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_2/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.java?view=markup#l1526) for how to code that. Much too broad for an answer here.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for your reply. `XWPFTrackRun` extends `XWPFRun` to insert text with track changes [XWPFTrackRun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71941703/apache-poi-insert-text-in-a-paragraph-and-view-track-changes-in-a-word-document) 
The idea of ​​this development is to search for a specific word and just after add a new word `XWPFTrackRun` with track changes to accept or reject

Answer (score 0):

you have solve the direction of write when it doesn't support 'insert',but it also doesn't support "read's insert"!

so how to do the opposite operation? such as

```
para1.getRuns().forEach(x1 -> {
//i can get deltext by using api "                     x1.getCTR().getDelTextArray(0);
"
//but i can't get inserttext by official api , because "x1.getCTR().getInsTextArray(0)" is unexisting!

//And 
"x1.getCTR().getInstrTextArray(0)" it doesn't work !


});
```